# Given MxN Matrix, count number 0s whose row and column consists of only one ZERO

Tags: javascript, arrays, algorithm, matrix, data-structures

For Example:

Input:

```
//MxN matrix
matrix = 
  [
    [ 0, 0, 1 ], 
    [ 1, 1, 0 ], 
    [ 0, 1, 1 ]
  ]
```

Output:
      1 (Because we only have (1,2) index having 0 whose row and column is having only one 0)

I have tried following:

I am getting all zero elements from Matrix.

Then storing them into HashMap as following:

```
Indexes which has 0s : [(0,0), (0,1), (1,2), (2,0)]

Hashmap["Row 0"] = 2;
HashMap["Row 1"] = 1;
HashMap["Row 2"] = 1;
HashMap["Col 0"] = 2;
HashMap["Col 1"] = 1;
HashMap["Col 2"] = 1;
```

The 1s in Hash map are (Row 1, Row 2 and Col 1, Col 2)
I have to get (1,2)

Unable to code for this approach and is there any better approach.

Comment: @adiga Updated with my approach.

Comment: It feels to me like you could implement something like the following. Put together a list of rows or columns with two or more zeros. On a copy of the matrix, remove (or cross out, just make all entries a 9, say) these rows or columns. Count the number of zeros that remain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your approach can be optimized to use two arrays instead of a hash map (should be faster):

```
  var matrix = [
    [ 0, 0, 1, ],
    [ 1, 1, 0, ],
    [ 0, 1, 1, ],
  ];

  // count zeroes on rows and columns
  var row0 = new Array(matrix.length).fill(0);
  var col0 = new Array(matrix[0].length).fill(0);

  for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
      if (!matrix[i][j]) {
        row0[i]++;
        col0[j]++;
      }
    }
  }

  // count single zeroes on their respective row and column
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < matrix.length; i++) {
    for (var j = 0; j < matrix[i].length; j++) {
      if (!matrix[i][j] && row0[i] == 1 && col0[j] == 1) {
        console.log(i, j);
        count++;
      }
    }
  }
  console.log(count);
```

Comment: Is there any optimized way in regards to Time Complexity and Space Complexity.

Comment: The code above runs in O(n<sup>2</sup>) time and space complexity and requires O(n) additional memory (the `row0` and `col0` arrays). This is asymptotically optimal, because the input matrix has n<sup>2</sup> elements. You can make a few constant optimizations, but I chose not to, for clarity. For example, in the second matrix pass you only need `row0[i]` for the current row `i`. This means that you can do away with the array `row0` and compute one (scalar) value at the beginning of each row. This saves O(n) space.